# How to store multiple data in an array of structure in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

i'm quiet new with programming and i'm stuck with a problem.

I want to store values in an array of structure.

I initialized a structure containing char and created an array which is in my main.

The main goal is to store an alias and it's initial command so i though about a structure.

```
//Structure defining how to store the data with alias and command associated.
typedef struct
{
    char alias_replacing[100];
    char command_replaced[100];
} Alias;


void createAlias(char *alias, Alias *array){

 const char delimiter_egal[2] = "=";
 const char delimiter_quote[2] = "'";
 char *command_to_replace = malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);
 char *original_command = malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);

 //Pick the alias that needs to be created
 command_to_replace = strtok(alias, delimiter_egal);

 //Store the alias in a struct
 strcpy(array->alias_replacing,command_to_replace);

 //Pick the command we need to substitute
 original_command = strtok(NULL,delimiter_quote);

 //Store the command associated in a struct
 strcpy(array->command_replaced,original_command);

 array++;

}

char *alias_searching (char *command_to_look_for, Alias *array){

 char *command_alias_found = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);

 //We go through all the alias created until we find the one we want
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
 {

    printf("array[i].alias_replacing : %s array[i].command_replaced : %s\n",array[i].alias_replacing,array[i].command_replaced);

    //If we find the alias corresponding, we store the value of the corresponding command into command_alias_found
        if (strcmp(command_to_look_for,array[i].alias_replacing))
        {
            strcpy(command_alias_found,array[i].command_replaced);
            printf("Command found : %s \n",command_alias_found);
            break;
            }
 }

    return command_alias_found;
    free(command_alias_found);
}
```

When i create alias and run alias_searching to find them i however only see the first value. The other values are not stored.

Thinking the the problem come from array++, i also tried to do something like : array[i].alias_replacing and changing the i everytime an alias is created, but this also didn't work.

Do you guys have any recommandations/advises ?

Thank you very much for your support.

Maxime

Comment: Please post [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you think `array++;` is doing?

Comment: Hint: `array++` has absolutely no effect. Removing it won't change the program's behaviour at all.

Comment: regarding: `char *command_to_replace = malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);` and 
 `char *original_command = malloc(sizeof(int)*1024);`  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the struct fields are only 100 bytes so why be allocating 1024 bytes?

Comment: when calling `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful, before using the returned pointer

Comment: the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely no effect (other than cluttering the code).  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: `char *command_to_replace` is mallocing `sizeof(int) * 1024` bytes, and then being copied into a char of only size 100.  Also the reference to `command_to_replace` is lost upon leaving scope of the function without freeing the memory.

Comment: when defining a struct, you should always include a `tag` name as most debuggers use the tag name to be able to work with/display the individual fields within the struct.

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)`   how do you know there are only 3 items in the array?  wouldn't it be much better to pass the actual number of (filled in) entries in the array, then use that number in the `for()` statement?

Comment: this line: `free(command_alias_found);` will never be executed because the prior line is: `return command_alias_found;`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: there's no reason to `malloc` either of the blocks of memory for `command_to_replace` or `original_command` as you're using them to store the return values of `strtok` - wasteful memory leak

Comment: this line: `array++;` in the function:  `createAlias()` is only modifying the passed parameter (on the call stack) and has no effect on the caller's data.  While the following is not a fix, note: to change where a pointer points, the address of the pointer must be passed, not the contents of the pointer.  so the caller would say something like: `createAlias( newdata, &oldarray );` and the signature for `createAlias()` would be `void createAlias(char *alias, Alias **array)` Notice the double dereference.  Then all references to `array` in the function would need to be updated.

Comment: Thank you for the advises. @user3629249, what do you use in this case to point to the data ? *array.alias_replacing ?

Comment: @MaxUt, a caveat: need to pay attention to the precedence of the C operators.   So, if the parameter is: `Alias **array`  then accessing a field in one entry of the array would be similar to: `(*array)[index]->field`